# Max number of follow redirects for webClient with ReactorClientHttpConnector

Tags: redirect, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

I've seen this concept in `httpClient` from `org.apache.http.client` library and I want to reproduce it. How the WebClient would follow and stop after 3 redirects.

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.create()
        .responseTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(2000))
        .followRedirect(true);

WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
        .baseUrl("https://test.com")
        .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(client))
        .build();
```

Answer (score 2):

The expected way to do that is to use the following and provide a predicate:

```java
reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient#followRedirect(BiPredicate<HttpClientRequest, HttpClientResponse> predicate)
```

like this:

```java
    HttpClient.create()
        .followRedirect((req, res) -> req.redirectedFrom().length < 3);
```